# not enough input arguments Matlab

Tags: matlab, cubic-spline

This is the clamped cubic spline code, but in the first line (
`n = length(X);`) mark an error, MATLAB says there's not enough input arguments, honestly I don't know why. Somebody help me please.

```
function [a,b,c,d]=ClampedCubicSpline(X,a,FPO,FPN)        
n = length(X);        
m = length (a);        
for i=1:n;        
    a(i)=X(2,i);        
end        

for i=1:n-1;        
   h(i)=X(1,i+1)-X(1,i);        
end        

alpha(1) = (3/hi(1))*(a(2)-a(1)) - 3 * FPO;        
alpha(n) = 3*FPN - (3/hi(n-1))*(a(n)-a(n-1));        
for i=2:n-1;        
    alpha(i)=3/h(i)*(a(i+1)-a(i))-3/h(i-1)*(a(i)-a(i-1));        
end    
l(1)=2*h(1);        
mu(1)=.5;        
z(1)=alpha(1)/l(1);        
for i=2:n-1;        
    l(i)=2*(X(1,i+1)-X(1,i-1))-h(i-1)*mu(i-1);        
    mu(i)=h(i)/l(i);        
    z(i)=(alpha(i)-h(i-1)*z(i-1))/l(i);        
end        

l(n)=h(n-1)*(2-mu(n-1));        
z(n)=(alpha(n)-h(n-1)*z(n-1))/l(n);       
c(n)=z(n);      

for i=n-1:-1:1;        
    c(i)=z(i)-mu(i)*c(i+1); 
    b(i)=(a(i+1)-a(i))/h(i)-h(i)*(c(i+1)+2*c(i))/3; 
    d(i)=(c(i+1)-c(i))/(3*h(i)); 
end
for i=1:n-1;        
    x=X(1,i):0.1:X(1,i+1); 
    y=a(i)+b(i)*(x-X(1,i))+c(i)*(x-X(1,i)).^2+d(i)*(x-X(1,i)).^3; 
    hold on; 
    plot(x,y,'b'); 
end
```

[here the screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEe4d.jpg)

Comment: You should run the function not using the `F5` or the `run` button. Instead, for a function you have to specify all of the inputs of the function. For instance: `ClampedCubicSpline(rand(1,10),rand(1,5),0.1,0.2)`. Be aware that the size of the input variables depends on the problem you are trying to solve, and my comment just shows an example.

Comment: I know, I know how to run it, like you said in your comment. but the error it's still there.Don't you see it ?

Comment: also thanks for editing the program.

Comment: Verify you don't have a local implementation of `length` function (in your working folder). Try stepping into `length`, using the debugger...

Comment: give me screen shot of error message

Comment: @AboLregal Why would you need a screen shot of text? Surely pasting the actual text of the error message would be sufficient, wouldn't it?

Comment: no screen shot tell me location of the error and all details i need
so when i see it I can guess what is rong

Comment: Abo Lregal I published the screenshot

Comment: @AboLregal Again, what does that screen shot tell you that the exact text of the error message wouldn't? In what way is an image of text better than the text itself?